# Can I use Command in Silverlight Button to switch between Save/Cancel logic?

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

Sorry I couldn't think of a better title.

What I have is a Silverlight user control which has a button Save currently which calls WCF to save a data object.

I want to be able to control this button appearance (or perhaps 2 buttons - one is hidden) in a way that:

- if there are changes on the object the button says Save
- if there are no changes the button says Close

I can check object for changes if I call a method say HasChanges. But there is no event which might notify me that a change has happened.

**Can I use ICommand for that purpose somehow?**

(I might add an event and make sure it will be fired each time user changes something but that's something I'd rather not to do).

Comment: Hmm...well usually it's a bad idea to implement such an interaction. Problem is, that is not obivious for the user how the operation can be cancelled. If he should not be able to, I would speak of a bad user experience, since there are not much use cases, in which such a behavior is necessary. So if you want to provide a good user experience I'd recommend you to provide a *Cancel* and a *Save* button. The *Save* button could be disabled as long there are no changes to commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I can only think about the solution you mention. Adding an event every time a property is changed. You can centralize it for the whole class though to avoid adding boiler plate code to every property.

If you are using MVVM and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can query your `HasChanges` method in the `OnPropertyChanged` that should be fired in the setter of the properties with `OnPropertyChange("xyz")`

```
class ClassA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _name;
    public bool Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));


        IsSaveEnable = HasChanges();
    }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to use the common validation area in the `IDataErrorInfo` implemention. But probably not the right place to put this logic

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Finally a specific attached property with this behaviour could be created. In other words the idea would be to manually implement the functionality of the EventToCommand pattern and add your custom logic there.

Regarding the command enabling/disabling if you are using DelegateCommand or RelayCommand you can call the command RaisePropertyChanged to enable/disable the button automatically